# ActivatedRoute.queryParams is undefined after screen refresh in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

Please help!

So I have the following url

```
https://xxx.io/#/route1/yyyyyyyy?tj=3&bd=7
```

And when I navigate to it, I have code the following code:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log('tj: ' + res.tj)
        console.log('bd: ' + res.bd)
```

Now this prints what I expect, which is tj: 3 and bd: 7

But when I refresh the screen, this res.tj and res.bd are undefined.
How can this be?

Initially this was happening because I noticed that the url when I refreshed the screen had changed to:

```
https://xxx.io/#/route1/yyyyyyyy%3D3&bd%3D7
```

But this was due to url encoding issues, so I added a CustomUrlSerializer, like so:

```
import { UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {

  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    const dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    return dus.parse(url);
  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
      const dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
      let path = dus.serialize(tree);
      return path.replace("%3F", "?").replace(/%3D/g, "=");
  }
}
```

And this fixed that issue so the url is correct again after the refresh:

```
https://xxx.io/#/route1/yyyyyyyy?tj=3&bd=7
```

But res.tj and ts.bd are still undefined!!!

Have been stuck on this for hours so hoping someone can shed light on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you change url? By ``Router`` ``navigate``?

Comment: Yep, and then pass in the query params as navigation extras...

Comment: Might be a dumb question (not very familiar with Angular's routing), but where is that `#`/anchor part of the URL coming from? It seems very weird to me to have query parameters be *after* the hashtag in an URL. Can you post an example of how you're generating these URLs, and how your routes are defined?

Comment: The # is there due to the HashLocationStrategy that I am using. Don't think that is the issue, as the route successfully has the query params when I navigate to that url the first time, but then on a refresh it is undefined...

Comment: Can you provide sample of code when you call ``navigate``?

Comment: can you try? 
 preserveQueryParams: true ; read here: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: @Vivek yep that did the trick, thanks so much!

Comment: @Buczkowski thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jeto thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1974753 good, I'll add that as an answer, perhaps easier for someone else to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Angular [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) interface has a property `preserveQueryParams`, setting it to `true` might help in your case

Typical usage:

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { preserveQueryParams: true });
```

Comment: Just in case: preserveQueryParams is deprecated, use queryParamsHandling instead